# In Google Form, when score of quiz is released, can the automated email to respondent be sent to owner as well using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When score of quize that is set up with collecting email address with respondent input is released, a Google-automated email is sent to the collected email, which shows the score and hyperlink (embedded in 'View') to the responded form with feedbacks. now Can I make it, using App Scripts send the same email to the owner / or if easier any other email collected in the form? I need to access that hyperlink.

Google sends out this email behind gmail of the owener so there is no trace in the Sent box of the email. Google doesn't allow adding or changing the collected email address. Google spreadsheet does not take feedback so there is way-around with Google sheet.